# Changing text color of tabs

Tags: tab

Can we change the text color of Custom tabs in salesforce? My requirement is I need to change the text color of Custom tabs. If color cannot be changed, can we change the font style of the text like changing it to Italics or Underlining the text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set the style of the active and inactive tabs using CSS. For that set the `tabClass` and `inactiveTabClass` attributes:

```
<style>
.activeTab  {
    color:red; 
}

.inactiveTab { 
    color:green; 
}
</style>

<apex:tabPanel tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
    <apex:tab label="tab one"></apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="tab two"></apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by "custom tabs", you mean a primary or subtab in the console, you can achieve this by using the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit and call the API : setTabTextStyle()

Example:

> sforce.console.setTabTextStyle('color:blue;font-style:italic;', myTabId, callback);

where myTabId is the tab Id on which you want to change the text style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about custom object tabs, then you should go to:

*Setup* --> *Create* --> *Tabs*

[image]

There you will see tabs for each custom object. If you click *Edit* next to it, you will be able to change the Tab Style and optionally choose a Home Page Custom Link to show as a splash page the first time your users click on this tab